# A word that means "uncovering the truth about something"

Tags: verbs, adverbs

I am looking for a word that means the act of or the effect of revealing the truth of an assertion (for instance a statement made in a news report).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a word that connotes an instance, subsequent to the actual _revelation_ or _disclosure_ of information, which, coming from the media, is very likely to be no more than rumors, or _assertions_, as you put it. I guess that would be the _confirmation, verification,_ or perhaps even _corroboration_ of the assertions made... no?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We have a strict rule on single word request and please write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used. You can click on the tag to read more information. http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: Like [factchecking?](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fact-check)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for "*expose*":

> #### [Expose](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/expose/)
>
> verb
>   
>   5. to make known, disclose, or reveal (intentions, secrets, etc.).

For example, in [this title](http://www.academia.edu/1030432/Revealing_the_Rot_How_to_use_social_media_to_expose_corruption_and_mismanagement_at_both_local_and_national_levels), *expose* means to make known or reveal.

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmhmmmm.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question, many don't. I've neatened up some of the formatting and removed your bit about '*vet*', as it wasn't explained and didn't seem to fit the question; anyway, one answer per answer is good enough. Finally, you might want to put it into an example sentence (other than the book title).

Answer (score 0):

I think **reveal** would fit the part:

> The spymaster **revealed** the courtier's plot.

Or **disclose**:

> The spymaster **disclosed** the guest's identity to the court.

Comment: Can you include a link to an online dictionary to back up your answer?